# Field is never assigned to, and will always have a default value 0

Tags: c#

I have searched similar results and there have been a couple of questions that match up with mine, but none give me the solution I am looking for. My code field radius1 keeps setting itself back to zero. I know why, it is because it is in the initial class, so whenever the class is called radius1 is set to zero. How do I go about fixing this to where I can call another method and keep radius the same? Here is my code:

```
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public static double radius1;


    public Circle(double radius)
    {
       radius1 = radius;
    }

    public static double ShowArea()
    {
        return Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius1, 2.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post how you are using this class

Comment: It's very suspicious to combine static member data and constructor arguments like that.

Comment: Just remove static word from the class

Comment: If you want to make many instances of `Circle`, each with a possibly different radius, you want to eliminate the word `static`, because you want the area of “this circle”. If you want to be a set of utility operations on a circle then eliminate the fields and just pass the radius in to `ShowArea`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "code field radius1" does *not* keep setting itself back to zero.

You either:

- never set it to anything other than its default value, which is zero, or
- you do set it to non-zero and then you have some other code which you have not shown us which sets it to zero. That's because it is `public`, so any other piece of code may modify it.

To fix, drop the `public static` part, and drop `static` from the `ShowArea()` function, and modify all of your code so that it does not require anything to be static.

Comment: Well, since "Field is never assigned to, and will always have a default value 0" is a compile-time warning, and at compile-time the value is never set (in a `static` way, that is), the value is "kind of" always zero. At least to the compiler, that is

Comment: ^Yes, that is the issue I am having. The value is always zero, apologize for the wording. How do I work around the compiler. It does require static because the methods are going on a aspx webpage

Comment: @jjmart92 So... this is for an ASP.NET application? That's even worse. Why? Open two browsers and you'll see

Comment: I don’t understand why you think “static is required”